# How to Run Subprocess in Views.py -- Django

Tags: django, django-views, subprocess

I am trying to run a script with the source `scripts/earnings.py` with the `symbol` argument that is generated from the user. The output is a matplotlib graph that I am trying to put in my template.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import subprocess
from backtests.scripts import earnings

def index(request):

    if 'symbol' in request.GET:
        symbol = request.GET.get('symbol','Invalid Symbol')
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol
    else:
        symbol = request.session['symbol']


    process = subprocess.run(["python earnings", "symbol"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    output = process.stdout

    return render(request, 'backtests/earnings.html', {'symbol' : symbol, 'output' : output})
```

As of now, I get the error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python earnings': 'python earnings'

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to import the python function you're running from *earnings.py* and call the function directly, and then use the return value of that function instead?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's a problem of path. try with ```["python scripts/earnings.py", "symbol"]```

Comment: @dirkgroten depending on how the script is written, it might keep global state and not be suitable to be imported into a long-running process

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to invoke `subprocess.run` is with each part of your command as a separate list entry:

```
    process = subprocess.run(["python", "earnings.py", "symbol"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

As @Bestastttung commented, your path is probably wrong too. Try `scripts/earnings.py`, or the absolute path to the file.

Comment: yep but i still think there'll be a problem with the path of earnings.py, as the root_path is not in /scripts, where the file earnings.py is.

Comment: @Bestasttung You are right, added that to the answer